# jquery find tag not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There i make a navigation bar and make a another unordered list
I'm use find for display it . but it not work

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".kl > #nav__ul1-show").click(function(){
  $(this).find(".nav__ul1").show();
 });
});
```

```css
.nav__ul1{
 display: none;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding:0px 10px 10px 10px;
 background-color: gray;
}
.nav__ul1 li{
 display: block;
 padding: 6px;
}
.nav__ul1 li a{
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.nav__ul2{
 display: none;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-default nav__b">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
          <button class="btn btn-info navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#my2">
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="my2">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="kl">
            <a href="#" id="nav__ul1-show">ELE</a>
            <ul class="nav__ul1">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Mobile <i class="fa fa-facebook pull-right"></i></a>
                <ul class="nav__ul2">
                  <li><a href="#">samsung <i class="fa fa-facebook pull-right"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">sony</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">nokia</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Lg</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Mobile Accessories</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Laptop</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Televisions</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">MEN</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Women</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">help</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Whats with all the dots?

Comment: when i submit my question is not accept.... so i use dots

Comment: It tells you what the problem is since you ain't able to submit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `nav__ul1` is not a child of `#nav__ul1-show`,use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to target immediately following sibling.

Also directly use ID selector to bind event handler.

```
  $(" #nav__ul1-show").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".nav__ul1").show();
  });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(" #nav__ul1-show").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".nav__ul1").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.nav__ul1 {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.nav__ul1 li {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px;
}

.nav__ul1 li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav__ul2 {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-default nav__b">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="btn btn-info navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#my2">
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
          </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="my2">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="kl">
          <a href="#" id="nav__ul1-show">ELE</a>
          <ul class="nav__ul1">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Mobile <i class="fa fa-facebook pull-right"></i></a>
              <ul class="nav__ul2">
                <li><a href="#">samsung <i class="fa fa-facebook pull-right"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sony</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">nokia</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Lg</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Mobile Accessories</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Laptop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Televisions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">MEN</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Women</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">help</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

OR traverse up to [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)  then use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(this).parent().find(".nav__ul1").show();
```